# Subset-sum one way function is one way on it's iterates if subset-sum is one-way

Tags: one-way-function

Working through the Moni Naor's slides from his lecture [Foundations of cryptography](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7E/naor/COURSE/foundations_of_crypto.html) (Lecture 3), the slides state that the subset sum function is one-way on its iterates if it is one-way, where the subset-sum function is earlier defined as:
$f: \{0,1\}^{mn+n} \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{mn+m}$:
$$f(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n, b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n) =
(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n, \sum_{i=1}^n b_i a_i \mod 2^m)$$,
where $b \in \{0,1\}^n, 0 \leq a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \leq 2^m$

One way on its iterates is defined as:

A function $: \{0,1\}^* \rightarrow \{0,1\}^*$ is called one-way on its iterates, if

- $f$ is a polynomial-time computable function
- For every probabilistic polynomial-time algorithm $A$, every positive polynomial $p()$ and all sufficiently large $n$'s: for all $k \leq p(n)$
  $$Pr[A(f^{k}(x)) \in f^{-1}(f^{k}(x))] \leq \frac{1}{p(n)}$$
  where $x$ is chosen uniformly in $\{0,1\}^n$ and the probability is over all possible values of $x$ and all possible coin tosses of $A$

I don't understand how $f^{2} = f(f(x))$ is even defined for the subset sum function? What's the reason that the subset-sum function is one way on its iterates?

Comment: Should $a_N$ be $a_n$ in your first equation? Unclear as it stands. And the slides are not much help. No one is going to go through all the slides to figure out a definition.

Comment: Corrected thanks. I included the slides for reference, the definition should be complete.